Draw and filter Charts in App Script Web app
I am trying to draw a chart on a Web App HTML page, fetching data from Google Sheets through my Apps Script function.
My GAS Code
// Data For Line Chart

function draw_chart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXX');
  var metrics_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data_s');
  var lastrow = metrics_sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcolumn = metrics_sheet.getLastColumn();
  var values = metrics_sheet.getRange("A1:X").getValues();
  /* Find Last Index of the Non Blank cells */
  const range = metrics_sheet.getRange("A1:X"+lastrow).getValues();
  var index_values  = lastrow - range.reverse().findIndex(c=>c[0]!='');
  var temp = "A1:X"+index_values;
  var values = metrics_sheet.getRange(temp).getValues();
  var pat_data1 = JSON.stringfy(values);
  return pat_data1;  
}

Sample Output of the draw chart function
[["Region","date","volume"],
["All","2024-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",100],
["All","2024-05-30T18:30:00.000Z",403],
["All","2024-06-30T18:30:00.000Z",678],
["All","2024-07-30T18:30:00.000Z",700],

["North","2024-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",90],
["North","2024-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",200],
["North","2024-06-30T18:30:00.000Z",500],
["North","2024-07-31T18:30:00.000Z",300],

["South","2024-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",10],
["South","2024-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",203],
["South","2024-06-30T18:30:00.000Z",178],
["South","2024-07-31T18:30:00.000Z",400]]

Loading all my Libraries here
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

I understand arrayToDataTable accepts Array of Array,so I did this
<script type="text/javascript">   
    
      google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

      function drawchart(){        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displaychart).draw_linechart();
      }
      function displaychart(c_data1){
        var chartdata =  new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(c_data1),false);
        console.log(chartdata);        

      //Setting Chart Options
      var options={
        title: 'Line Chart Example',
        is3D: true
      }
      // Draw chart passing some options
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
      chart.draw(chartdata,options);
      }
      </script>

<select id="city">
    <option value="National">National</option>
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
     </select>
<div id="line_chart" class="line_cont"></div>

I am getting the error

All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

For the above error, I took this answer as an reference
Google Chart All series on a given axis must be of the same data type confusing error
And I tried this
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string','region' );
        data.addColumn('date','date');
        data.addColumn('number','volume');

        var arrMain=[];
        for(i=0;i<c_data1.length;i++){
console.log(c_data1[i].region) // returns undefined
          arrMain.push([c_data1[i].region,new Date(c_data1[i].date),c_data1[i].volume]);
        }

        data.addRows(arrMain); 

Again same error "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" console.log(c_data1[i].region) returns undefined.
What exactly I doing wrong here? I understand lot of down vote because lack of info I tired to convey my error again.

I think that in your showing script, at function filter_data(f_data){, this is not enclosed by }. Is this related to your current issue? Or, your showing script is not your whole script? If so, can you provide a sample spreadsheet including your whole script to correctly replicate your current issue?

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I'm confused. Do you want to change your question? If it's so, what will you do with this question?

Hi tanakie, I posted the question on an another approach to avoid confusion. Pls help me out in this question. Both are same but data approach is different.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I would like to ask my 1st comment again.

Yes this is my whole script

Apology for confusion, I have edited my post on my understanding so far on this. Pls help me with solution or working snippet. Thanks!!

Thank you for replying. From your updated question, about All series on a given axis must be of the same data type, when I saw your Sample Output of the draw chart function, the columns "A", "B" and "C" are strings, strings, and numbers, respectively. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, the data type must be the same. But, I do not know your expected result. So, by guessing your expected result, I proposed the modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Modification points:

In your Javascript, at google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displaychart).draw_linechart();, draw_linechart is called. But, in your Google Apps Script, the function name is draw_chart(). Is this draw_linechart?
From your updated question, about All series on a given axis must be of the same data type, when I saw your Sample Output of the draw chart function, the columns "A", "B" and "C" are strings, strings, and numbers, respectively. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, the data type must be the same. But, I do not know your expected result. So, the following modification is just my guess.

I guessed your expected result is as follows.

Your data has 3 columns "Region","date","volume", and your HTML has a dropdown list. When you change the dropdown list, for example, you select "South", you want to show the chart with the data of "South" in "Region". When "National" is selected, you want to use the data of "All" in "Region".

If my guess for your expected result is correct, how about the following modification?
Google Apps Script:
Please modify the function name from draw_chart() to draw_linechart.
HTML:
In this case, it supposes that the function draw_linechart works fine. And, the values Sample Output of the draw chart function correctly returned. Please be careful about this.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

    let obj;

    function drawchart() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
        const [[, ...head], ...v] = JSON.parse(e);
        obj = v.reduce((o, [a, b, c]) => (o[a] = o[a] ? [...o[a], [new Date(b), c]] : [head, [new Date(b), c]], o), {});
        displaychart("All");
      }).draw_linechart();
    }

    function displaychart(key) {
      var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj[key], false);
      var options = {
        title: 'Line Chart Example',
        is3D: true
      }
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
      chart.draw(chartdata, options);
    }

    function selected(e) {
      displaychart(e.value == "National" ? "All" : e.value);
    }
  </script>

  <select id="city" onchange="selected(this)">
    <option value="National">National</option>
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
  </select>
  <div id="line_chart" class="line_cont"></div>
</body>

</html>

Testing:
When the above-modified HTML and Javascript are used with your value "Sample Output of the draw chart function", the following result is obtained.


Applying this now, Will check and accept.

Thanks Again, would you mind explaining this part const [[, ...head], ...v] = JSON.parse(e);
obj = v.reduce((o, [a, b, c]) => (o[a] = o[a] ? [...o[a], [new Date(b), c]] : [head, [new Date(b), c]], o), {}); If want to show all three values as multiline chart how would i modify this?

@Tpk43 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question 1 would you mind explaining this part const [[, ...head], ...v] = JSON.parse(e); obj = v.reduce((o, [a, b, c]) => (o[a] = o[a] ? [...o[a], [new Date(b), c]] : [head, [new Date(b), c]], o), {});, in this part, your value is parsed by "Region" and create an object. At that time, the string data is converted to the date object using new Date().

@Tpk43 About your new question 2, also I would like to support you. But I cannot understand the expected result of your new question. I apologize for this. So, can you post it as a new question and include more information? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'll be glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

@Tpk43 When you post your new question 2 as a new question, please include the expected result of show all three values as multiline chart. In the current stage, I cannot imagine the expected result of your new question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for my poor English skill.

Hi Tanaike, Sure will post a another question

@Tpk43 Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I will check it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78954768/google-multi-line-chart-format-data-apply-filter here is the question, pls take a look. Let me in case additional details required. Thank you so much!!
