How to Avoid Hardcoded DataTable to draw Google Multi Line Chart (Format data & apply Filter on the charts)
I am following the example from the Google Line chart documentation, My data is like this
[["SalesDiv","date","volume"],
["National","2024-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",100],
["National","2024-05-30T18:30:00.000Z",403],
["New City","2024-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",90],
["New City","2024-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",200],
["old City","2024-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",10],
["old City","2024-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",203]

On Tanaike advise, I have updated the code
My Script code is
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

    let obj;

    function drawchart() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
        const [[, ...head], ...v] = JSON.parse(e);
// This part of code I am not getting to make it Multiseries. Bear with me I am beginner in Javascript. This code displays only Lines series "NAtional" on Page Load, I want to make it display all three series.
        obj = v.reduce((o, [a, b, c]) => (o[a] = o[a] ? [...o[a], [new Date(b), c]] : [head, [new Date(b), c]], o), {});
        displaychart("All");
      }).draw_linechart();
    }

    function displaychart(key) {
      var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj[key], false);
      var options = {
        title: 'Line Chart Example',
        is3D: true
      }
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
      chart.draw(chartdata, options);
    }

    function selected(e) {
      displaychart(e.value == "National" ? "All" : e.value);
    }
</script>
<select id="sales_div">
    <option value="National">National</option>
    <option value="New City">New City</option>
    <option value="old city">old city</option>
     </select>
     <button id="srch_btn" onclick="filtering()"> Search </button> 
     <div id="line_cont" class="d_c"></div>

On Page Load - Expected output is this

On filtering the drop down and clicking the button, expected output is this


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. From JSON.Stringfy results from GAS Function:New Data, I cannot understand your showing image. Can you provide your expected result and the sample values needed to obtain your expected result? First, I would like to understand your question correctly.

@Tanaike - Edited with Expected result Image, My Question is How to avoid the DataTables which I created inside displaychart() function. Instead is there any other way to it dynamically to pass the data to draw chart?

Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the details of the relationship between New Data and your showing images?

Images are not related to New Data, I edited the question again. Images are to show my expected functionalities of the chart.

@Tanaike - Here I updated question with your suggestion. Pls let me know any additional details required. Thank you very much for your help
